# Как с помощью pack() запаковать массив с string значениями?

Tags: php

```
// Создаю массив
$aYearColor = array_fill(0,366,'#FFFFFF');  
// Запаковываю его
$aYearColorBlob = pack('a*', ...$aYearColor);
// Распаковываю
unpack('a*', $aYearColorBlob);
```

Но данный способ не сработает. На выходе будет array ( 1 => #FFFFFF );

И ошибка Warning:  pack(): 365 arguments unused in ...

Если массив числовой, то проблем нет, всё сработает:

```
$aYearOrder = array_fill(0,366,0);
$aYearOrderBlob = pack('i*', ...$aYearOrder);
unpack('i*', $aYearOrderBlob);
```

Прочитал, что:

> Для a, A, h, H число повторений определяет то, сколько символов взято
>   от одного аргумента данных

Но не пойму, как тогда добавить такой массив с string значениями и потом обратно его распаковать. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как в моём случае мне нужно хранить цвет в массиве, я перевёл из 16 в 10 систему и запаковал числовой массив.